# Cuando declaro una variable, ¿Le estoy asignando una espacio en memoria o primero la tengo que inicializar?

Tags: c++, variables, memoria

```
int x; //declarando una variable 
x = 5; //inicializando una variable
int y = 6 //declarando e inicializando una variable
```

¿Ocupa espacio en memoria cuando la declaro? ¿o todavía no?

Comment: Si, al ser declarada ya ocupa memoria. si es una variable global, el espacio lo ocupa desde que el programa arranca hasta que termina. Si es local, desde que la función se inicia hasta que retorna.

Comment: yo agregaria que al declararla si tiene un valor.. en el caso de c++, le asigno una posicion en la memoria y el valor que tomo es lo que habia en ese lugar en la memoria...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿ Ocupa espacio en memoria cuando la declaro ?

**Depende**.

### Teoría

La especificación del lenguaje determina que es posible obtener la dirección en memoria de **cualquier** variable (a diferencia de C, no es posible declarar variables `register`) **antes de asignarle ningún valor**. Con lo cual, la respuesta sería `ocupan espacio en memoria desde que las declaras`.

### Práctica

#### Variables no-automáticas

Este tipo de variable es algo *complejo*: pueden declararse e inicializarse en archivos distintos ... con lo que conceptos tales como `declaración` o `asignación` no terminan de estar tan claros como pareciera ... y mas aun si tenemos en cuenta que, desde C++14, dichas variables pueden ser *plantillas*, y desde C++17, dichas variables se pueden declarar `inline` ... y, en todo caso, se inicializan a `0` si no les proporcionas un valor de forma explícita.

Cuando declaras una variable de este tipo, el compilador entiende que es **una promesa** por tu parte:

```
extern int X;
```

estás diciendo `Mira, compilador. En alguna parte, en otro archivo, hay una variable de nombre X. Palabra de programador.`

Estas declaraciones han de complementarse con **instanciaciones**: **tienes que cumplir tu palabra**:

```
int X = 10;
```

Pero ambas partes puede ir en archivos distintos, así que ... pueden darse casos *curiosos*; por ejemplo, si instancias `int x = 10`, pero no la declaras en ningún sitio ... ¡ la variable existe **antes** de que la declares !

En todo caso, este tipo de variables reservan su espacio **antes incluso** de que entres en tu función `main( )` ... ¡ su sola instanciación permite viajar en el tiempo !

#### Variables automáticas

Seguro que todos conocemos el famoso *experimento mental* del `gato de schrödinger`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
<sub>Tomada de [La Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo:Schrodingers_cat.svg)</sub>

Viene a decir que, en determinados sucesos, pueden darse varias situaciones **de forma simultánea**, y que es el propio hecho de *comprobar* (observar) la situación el que fuerza el *colapso* a un estado determinado.

Pues, con las variables automáticas, pasa algo parecido.

Ante una declaración

```
int x;
```

el compilador puede decidir **que no es necesaria**, aunque se le asigne un valor inicial `int x = 10;`

Las capacidades de optimización de los compiladores modernos son **abrumadoras**, y, si llega a la conclusión de que dicha variable **no se utiliza**, y su construcción/destrucción no conlleva efectos colaterales, puede decidir **no crearla**.

Por lo tanto, tenemos una *paradoja*: el estándar dicta que si ... pero el compilador decide que no, por lo que la variable se encuentra en ambos estados a la vez. Existe ... ¡ y no existe !

En estos casos, es el compilador el que decide. Podemos realizar acciones para inclinar su decisión en uno u otro sentido: obtener su dirección (con `&`), declararla `volatile`, usarla como argumento de una función `extern`, declararla como `const`, que sea una instancia de una clase con efectos laterales en su constructor/destructor (incluidos el que sean `extern`), ...

**Ahondando**

Hasta donde se, **el espacio** necesario para las variables automáticas se reserva **al entrar** a la función (no tengo claro si el [ABI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_binaria_de_aplicaciones) influye en esto). Pero, como casi todo en esta vida ... con matices:

```
int foo( ) {
  int A = 0;

  {
    float B = 0.0f;
    A += funct2( B );
  }

  {
    double C = 10.0;
    A += funct3( C );
  }

  return A;
}
```

Observa que el espacio ocupado por `B` y `C` **puede solaparse**. Puesto que son variables con ámbitos distintos, el compilador puede decidir que no vale la pena ocupar espacio de forma individual para ambas; puesto que `C` ocupa mas espacio, puede reservar solo el necesario para `A` y `C`, *compartiendo* este último con `B`.

<sub>**Nota**: durante la escritura de esta texto, no se hizo daño a ningún *gatito*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Ocupa espacio en memoria cuando la declaro?

Puedes consultar el tamaño de una variable usando el operador `sizeof()`:

```
std::cout << sizeof(x);
```

Este operador te devuelve el tamaño en bytes de cualquier variable y éste valor se calcula en tiempo de compilación.

En cualquier caso, en el momento en el que declaras una variable ya puedes almacenar un valor en ella. Es facil ver que para poder almacenar un valor en una variable se hace necesario que dicha variable tenga una región de memoria donde almacenar dicho valor. Por tanto es en el momento de la declaración cuando la variable ya ocupa espacio en el sistema.